# Enabling PHP 5.4 (fastcgi) for one of my plesk domains causes 500 error

Tags: linux, centos, plesk

So ive installed a brand new php handler for my plesk and registered it with plesk accordingly.

Now when i switch the php handler for one of my domains to the new 5.4 fastcgi it causes an internal server error 500.

This is not a fastcgi problem since 5.3 runs good on fastgci.
It only happens with 5.4.

Also i took a brand new 5.4 php.ini for this domain so that cant be it either.
Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you check your error log? I had many problems while upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the "mod_fcgid: read data timeout", Can you please try to increase it and check again our site